# The page is blank even after typing code in components page

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLSXu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I51wr.png)
Even after creating and writing code in header.component page the broswer page is still blank. Can someone help me fix this?

Was expecting a navbar with blue color